# Flutter svg Failed to find definition for url

Tags: flutter, svg

flutter_svg package error on flutter

> ════════ Exception caught by SVG
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown while parsing AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle:
> PlatformAssetBundle#f8f72(), name: "assets/plane.svg", colorFilter:
> null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: null, fontSize: 14, xHeight: 7))
> in _getDefinitionPaint: Failed to find definition for url(#a)
>
> This library only supports  and xlink:href references that are
> defined ahead of their references.
>
> This error can be caused when the desired definition is defined after
> the element referring to it (e.g. at the end of the file), or defined
> in another file.
>
> This error is treated as non-fatal, but your SVG file will likely not
> render as intended
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by SVG
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════ Failed to find
> definition for url(#a)
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="324" height="93" xml:space="preserve">
    <image width="324" height="93" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUQAAABdCAYAAADdRB8hAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAA CXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAABHl0lEQVR42u29d5wkR333/67qMD1pd2bz5SCdsnQSkpAABZDh QTbBNtgyxuHxYxv75+fn/GD7cQ4YjLOxzfNgg8GAjQFjhABJBImkAOIUQemSLt/t3eYwqbur6vmj w/TM7p7uQLoVYj4vrW6mp2N11ae+uaCHHnrooYceeuihhx566KGHHnrooYceeuhhZYhn8mS1Wm1t s9ms5nI5GQSBdF1XBkEgHccBkI7jyDAMbcdxhG3bs8A+IURttRuhhx566AGeYUKcn59/m5DWa43R OZBSSmELgSWllEhpSXCklA5CWMBBYcxfW5b1ASFEa7UbooceeujBfiZPpoV4yBLi1xFWTgAIAUJg EAgDBoE2EG85F3gHYIwxHxBC+KvdGD300MN3N+QzebKg2fyGEDwqpUCI6M8YA/GfMRpjDFobtDEY yIehepvW+ueMMc5qN0YPPfTw3Y1nlBCHhoaOSOQ9RhsjBBhjoj+if4H0XzBEsiLD2vB7SvF9xphn VGLtoYceejgdPKOEKIRY1Dq8FWPmBJF0KOUyZsqEFAWJFDmKMP+g6JFiDz30sHp4RgkRQGv9AJij iRwohMQY0ImUmEiNBoyOPgshANajzTvCMLxqtRulhx56+O7EM06IfX19U5aUH0iJLpEGDUtU5+Qv ghDa6M1Syv80xlxvjHnG762HHnro4WR4VkgnDMNbjNYLUkpSi2FKfHRIilLImBg18f6jxpj/A1y9 2o3TQw89fHfhWSHEZrN52LbkXVqpaENsK0wg0nAcUInn2Ri00hiDDJW+QBvzIWPMS40xz2isZA89 9NDDSnhWCHF4eLgRKHUXAmWM6Yj+jn3OmVCcRG2OtwNSSrQx65Xiz4Gtq91IPfTQw3cHnhVCFEIo v9n8IjAFZNTm5AMp+RHFIyb8GO8swGBpo15ojPmcMea8nqTYQw89PNt41hwXg4ODj1hSftPQJSHG HudISGwzZGpXBLRScciORBmzNVTqH4FLVruxeuihh+c3njVCFEI0w0D9Z1sUzCAjIUZEGG00yY8x gya/CcR1Sql3GmM2rXaD9dBDD89fPKuhLUoFd0ghjkKU1pyFyZJinLUSbTedf9HvjjG8RCnzN/W6 Wb/ajdZDDz08P/GsEmJ/f/8RhL4TQCAiUswQo+myJQJRjnNKhJCk+EUZLfp1rmf+zhizZrUbroce enj+4VklRCFE0yjzRYyZPemObQGxa7tJHS2JZq2Vfr3S+i+NMcOr1Wg99NDD8xPPejaIZVlfAZ5K vie8l4TfdNR6gNix0lkUQhuNIU3xQyv9ulDr3zLGDKx2A/bQQw/PHzzrhJjP558SUt6TfDfZD2lW XyYEJxEFsx5oaBMkoIzJK6V+XcMvGWP6V7sRe+ihh+cHzki+sDDmE0CQmBAN2cyVzhCcdLvIxiZm M1k0Mqq1KELff3MYhn9gjKmsdkP20EMP3/k4I4QYeN4jxuivRwUfouo3idvZmNiRkslUSWHabpWO zfG/GlFShl8OI0kxv4rt2EMPPTwPcEYIsQw1o/UtkVPZRFyYUZdTW6I5hZNl9omr6dgo9Wta8/PG GO+Mt2APPfTwvMGZUZmFaLque5cQYlwbgxQCbaIA7O48584Dn+68IKREKV1VWv2Z1vp3jTG5M9yG PfTQw/MEZ6zmoOM4jwnEU21bYWxPTMNqMh7naI+nPWdii5RSYrTxtDY/p5R6gzHGOqOt2EMPPTwv cMYIUQixIAUfMsYsTVuJkQRkx9+WV6FF58fE+xw5YcyIMfw98DO9ArM99NDD6eKMVpAxxgwu1uqH bNvOa63bRR4y5CelxJISIQVGJ2uviNT7nN6wEAjaxsg0RlFrLCnnLUv+GHC7EEKtchv30EMP3yE4 o1KUEGJKCvEZHRNdQm4iTs1DRISWOlnibdnish0SZEKGdBaf1Ub3aWP+SsGPrE6z9tBDD9+JOONq pUZ+Dkwz+iY6tGcR1UFEa7M0LvEk6JQwo2rcQRCci9Z/YYy55kw/Yw899PCdiTNOiK6du9do/URb 0hNLSE9rjda6ncDcIQ0uj4QUtWmr2WEYrlPafKBHij300MOp4MwTosuTUlr3QKdvRbT157bXma4s PjL7rIDEySJiSVGpcIs25j3GmIvO9LP20EMP31k444QohPCNEXdmw2wi9ThSn0U2HifzZ9IisqYr VCdrVTSp2i2IwnFiSfFcY8z/McZsX+0G76GHHp67WJV1Sowxbq1e320QG5Olm4XoLBALkT1QSokQ Mtmp46aXrOS37AOKeIkWg0Teb1niZ4QQ31iN5+6hhx6e21iVWD0hhC+F9TETBSXGxV+j8l7ZP5M6 WHR85Knk9mWuk65FQJwdo68wxrzNGHPeajx3Dz308NzGqgUvB+j/xLAAEVklEKKzEo4xmiRM59tB 4mxRWn+fMeYfjTGbV+vZe+ihh+cmVo0QrXx+n23LB1cKr0m+GgNGJxLit6jhi9hOGZsXldIvM8b8 Xa9sWA899JDFqhFiSYjjlm1/XkADEUmJxphYGuwu8vCtEWFHsYi0GKNBY6TS+jXG8G5jzLrVaoMe eujhuYVVzfcVxtxpjKkZnXiRk5jE9l9iXwxVOwNPGx39aZ0uSpXELnYuUAVGxGv6GQE69j4LCSCV 1q/RWr+1Vzashx56gFUmRNd175NCPqS1pmNNgWWQkB1xaI3oWJ0lQ4BLziOWfo/J1xiTM4YfBf6+ pz730EMPq14RxrLELYhkdfqTq8ZG66jgg+AkanT7PFHoYmfVnGxlbiEESms3DNVPAn/eq5DTQw/f 3Vh1AghDeQ/a7DVmZekwVp7T1fc6sOSwZKGqeIn7lU6aZPhJicHklNI/DfyuMWZktdukhx56WB2s OiEWi85+adtfSbJVloUQUTkwQyQhZvP5TsHfkqZDd2xrF6olilG0lda/BvzCardJDz30sDpYdUIU QswKKe7UxjSEWH4JASFii2EmXW+p7GcydSBMypnZ/TsL0LardIu286YaavXbxphf6tkUe+jhuw+r TogAedf9giXlBKYrHS/1OpuM06Szok17vdL279GHzlzoNrqoND1WJOfLKaXfDvxTLySnhx6+u/Cc IETguGM79yZS3FJ0p/SZds3E7P6Z750UeIpoF5sohKH6YeBTxphrjDGrkvPdQw89nFk8JwhRCGEU 6r8E+MsRYuJUFpm7jdRd3SbQDGVlpUmTPUn84aTslpgyBUJpfZmBjwG/aIzp666u00MPPTy/8JyR fIwxZ9cbzQ8buPwU9k0/y3jVvXS7WJ7wpCXbZJeo4nFBCbL+nIzdMrmOJeWkgA8DfwPsB8ypVPLu oYeT4UxOrvV6Pf0sMmsU5fP51W6G5xTs1b6BDA4KIe8wRl/GEsnVdJQIS0qGLRtWs9Kqfmb5DcaY ZWXGbGcNlRqSQvyiFOICIcSbgW+ExqhkrdPvVHJ8tgdkmPlsA4rkf8uh8wed/SABLbAsidYaBViZ oyyifaIAf5k5Wib/F4ZODWO5tpDd1wa0XkGNii8TmZ2XP3F3SsCSa4ItVtbSZNxsy3UuET/2t3Is Qgg7ObbRaHT/lhzLCsc63dd1XRff90EIIcA5ySM7Ih4stp1eIlHk5oFpYFYI0WSV8JwayUEQfO9i vf6hXM6rqDBESonSCtt24s4OCTkCackwKUXHQlUYsYQTT6V24rK/Zyp4C1AGsceS8jYjedCCx4wx TzSarVbO86J703qFRpXLdl/JMhXB6RyU6b6iva82Js3/7pBwO287xXLkJ6UQlpR52vySwGNpx7aA bnFCxvt2H58D3C5CtBTkUUuapxCdp4MQcxrcaNUxEvIRliULWmu5AiG6Wmv3JIRYXIkQBbjamNwK hCgklJZ9cREh5hDSWeG8wix3bPvsVvRW2+8sWhMItEGio0eLCh+3X3NcTtlCrkB40UlPZg6zWGHs G4xc5n1mz26BWaG3CSFAms7MiMzvWFEdaNF1TQyYBrBoYMFoJqQldknYA3wJ2CeE0JwBPKcI0RhT qNUbX0OIi5OmMibqJJ2+k+iLVgqEwLIsrERtJltOTCT/Rd/SArMi6mSnK9mlnuz2zSilAq31sZzn 7QejjdYFsWy7rkiIrjFLZ9Vl3r4tBU7Eyx2EWGCpkOsKsLsI0SIir1NCMrk8nfSc7JtMTtnf45zx JQN6OQleG91xLZN5qPR9pf92vhKxDF20b26Znwxd5xOZ65n0wCV9ZJnju7WU5Q02Jj1f5z4nudbz BV2anEA8Leuky4Ag0FojhJgUiAeNMY8IWz5sQg7aNnuFEMee6dt9zr2BQKm31uuN37FtG601Usp4 sGUlqaRgAyitEAhsx0lJseMBu8J4lowmOgdH9zHZY41oL1GQtJ4QURFbaUmMNiilIkLuHojRiZe0 ujidV9B9+7HkKqV8usNOs7RuVwMtOduzgG6OWG6XtLp6+/lF9rgsd61gOck+mnmaa5jTuJfkmslv p7Lt6fZd7tiOfZfrYye531OByfTttF2T709TImDFe+g+52ncY2oaS7Q0QVMgDgvBXiPE3RI+Bzzw TK2//pwjxIVW60KUvk9CMRHCs1JBt6SYFIawLRspZbzkQFdtxW6JgSzpiSVyhVlukC1XtzE50ESL WmX7xLJ9Y6UOI55m3+4Olb2/kyT4nBa+ddZ8ZrDcXGVOvv+q3u+38ZynTCRdbdN9WBYdXbVrw+l2 j5Vu7+nOs8xwOe22EEQCRvc46xYEMlfUAg4Yoz8lpfw4cIhIxf6WeodYybC+WuL77OxsNed5HwtC dYMlZYcKnEhw3aQYLTEgsC0L27ZPeu9tx4xor98iQEYVJpZFcl2ZBm+TZsOk1+roNc+OZPWsc8CZ IpmVrrOM9C4y259W6iOz39M8ykmluFOYZJZIeV2JAcspBsteq/ugp3u2U9ttxXt9Wjy9RvvMXfc0 rnWyySD93VATsNMYPiYl/w4cOl1iFMaYy4BG/NcEFuN/VxRBn02yNMaIMNS/1Ww1/1Ba0kuvl0nD 05gopznaH9/3EQLy+QI5112m07S7Z1YyXGnIJJYhs8z27LN3L451KvaR5S627As2y+56ZoWip5Nc v9VzPp3kl7lOEhVFF5Esq9Yud+zJpPIusWql4IQOqUe057ws4XXvJ7rPzwpktszGlUhvxe3x9ZZr 2qeVtLubRXSR+jLvoftaSyaBJaaizs9plfzMNaJQoJMrPd1OQhE7UJdKkCbEmANSyn8FbgOeFELU OQUIY8w+Inf3pDFmDpiIv08Ds8BU/DdjjJnQWs/Nzs4GhUIBx3FwHOeUmvxUSDQjrb6o0Wp+UIXq LMu2CIMQpZcanYUQ2LaN6zhR1RqjO2o+ZG9KLtegcik5Zg3liXTSfoGJ9zp7H885q8Ozh2eakU/R 9mXMKe5/CnZI0l2WTmDdfUQAOkuC2eO7JETTRcLLEdRKA72DXFa4XvLbKUnIdJH46aCbBbtuajlV /VRU/uxDBEGY+gaklJHd3ZKRD0CIk5LhyYT4djsaRBRppYGngPcDHycixpPerf2+f33ffLmvvF4K 6wWTU5PMz88R+CFOzg5HR8bCdevWBX2lcmjbtsrn8y3P8/xCoTAFHAfGjTETwDhwApgQQtSIJMzk 31lg0bSXzovbuvNxpqenCcNQ2LY9AIyGQaiDMEQqhWVZeLkoCkNKiRQynk3aLywbltP2Ji/Tosu2 clvfibx9ybGdhJnYM7U2KW0aHReslQIR39dpYQUv6NN2rtWwn3Vd8+kcD6d1vhWea8XTL/FoZO5p pX06Lrd0+3LS1Qom447nTwZhIq0kl14pFEqw9DWLzPWy6fXdJ+iW2Lql0m7CWMmZ03Ha7D13Sg3p j1mzQOpXzNopV+gL3ZNFoBSWJbEsKx1H0rFRSqGNwUrNY53tQvf1MtfQWrOwsEi90aJYyHPs+FEs yxM517GKee/sUOk/sm3nF/Oe83FjzAeBh4QQrWXbwhhz/vj4+EWf+OQnLvzoxz5qF0vlTWvG1m5r NOoXnTh+vLBv31MILUR/fz8jIyOMjY2xfv16NmzYQKFQIJfL0dfXR19fH6VSSVeqlflyqTzled60 bduTwGHgCHAg/vyUMeb45NRU3RhDGASmWCwCbBaW9XLPzb1KSPk9WuuyEALLttOc5Q4lNu49iagN tIvHLvugS3tnQnDZc7YHQaesmByt4qUKsp5kYyIvc0TUp8aI2TCVkyIraZwK+TxTTpYzgW/lXlci zoxqIDLE1L3Psm0uljn9yTy88f86SGAFO2C3xzjdRXTydcfn7rY5VXvrCm25xLxw0sknE8N1MhPE ChP3ks1dRBr4AY5tt+3v8c0ppWKnqFhqBskICmLpMGb/4UO8/yMfZ/xYg5/5se/nrX/2Ftas3Y60 NNdddyVPHT5KvdHEDn2uv+7KPde/+Kp/AN6znBrdKURFRQxyc3Nz+R07dpTv2XGPN9Q3dM7ZZ599 5ezs7A07duxY/8ADD7jj4+OebdvlZrPplMtlRkdH6evrQxuD67kU8gU8L0elUmFwcJCBgUFTqVZa a8bW+NVKpV4slVtSyt3GmG+Gvr+7WCyOlMrlHxVCbJJCelnuUtqglco0XkR8hkhaNFqjYukw8TIv 0y9TEb3dUTOB3F2NIRCoeJqWMna2xE4UraL1XCLnTaRmKWVSgj2ZhLdEKsiIM91xbZ1rVWcq/Cyn zSCiZAlzGkTbhdQG2q03LvccXYO8W1ppn/Pkx2cnoG773JIBf7JHMpFnMlQhvh/gebnOaANj8IMA S0qkZbUnM1bgsY6Jsa1F6kzbLpGquvtRF6fozIWSJja6bbbR2mDJjHRk2u2aTUTouPckFpW2Iyl7 jOx6xuXaLW3erneQeHrlcjbFbhtitk922027iL7ZbJJzXQSCIAyxLAspJWEYYlkSIZ6+vEJ39NrX H36Yf/rQf/HYNyf4vV//KR7YcR8HxwWTEwdYt36QF17/Ih576iD+zDTShNz02lf6V26/8LO2Zf0m sDOrRp/WyImDe4fDMNxy6NChC+64444N999/f2V+fn7r0NDQtsVabfP8wnzu0MFDLCzMi2KxiLQt vEKB4eFh+vr6cGwLx3Upl8qUin04rkOpVKLS10/O8xgaHKFYKlIul+jrK5PP58nlcsjEtpARlwwZ TzGcVF1NZr2ENLOB3EnnSopFzM4t0N9XxrFtfN9Ha43jOFi2lb5kk3ZIMsR18h54Wr7n7HkzHXHp O4nOnDqeMp9PGaJNiMtKEsvcb2cgNh2DtMPR1PVZEEnZMm6vZstP7NDpoLCkhR8EGAye6xIEIX4Q UCzkMQYWa4uUikVCpajXGxQLhWghsjBkYnKKtWvGoolRJGSjOXpsnIFKP14hjyUlCwuLtFpNBgcG CJVifPw469auxRjNgUOHWTM2hpfL8dS+/YyMDFEulVJSE8Dc3BwnJibYunVrRL6AkAIVKnbt2cPG 9esplors2rWHvr4yoyMjICAMQh5/4gk2btxIf38fu3btxrIttm7ZwuTkFAcPHuSFV16B7wfcfe+9 XHH5CyiXy+na5ALYvWcvR44c4dprr+H4+DgPPfINXv1934tSiltvv50Xv+hqqpUqOx54gGKhwCUX X8Tep/Zz8OABrr76KprNJp+6/bP8wKtfRblU5PbPfJ5169Zy0YUXMDU9zfHjJ9i27WwajQbvfd+H +LE3/hCjo8N88EMfYcvG9Vx7zUvYu28fn7/jC/z4j74Bz/P4tw99mIsuPJ/LX3AZj3zzMQ4dPsyr v/eVdITkC2g2GuQ8D4lg5549bNqwAc/L4ftBSo5P2127Jp9v7tzJ5776IIcO1tk43MfrX3sdn73r 63zkox+kvjjJT//km7jvkd3UWz6z8/M4aH7+x3+IV1x/7QHHsX4fuEUIMQ+nmcscBz+Ox39fNcaI N73pTXmg/8SJE8MPP/pw5ejBowPHjx8/u1KpXFAoFM45MTGxYWJqOv+Zz3yh2l8p2LPTE3g5w/oN ZxHiMlQdRBtNf18fAK5rYVkCx3EpFDzy+QKlUplCqZ+BaoXBgUGqlX6KxSI5z8OxbSzLxrJk1OFC lUpKWmss24oWqNI6JkHD3PwcX/rSXew7tJ/5+TmqlQqOHTlmHNtiz5ETjA5VGesrwvgko5aLs24N u+sLzMzMUK1WGRwYIO/lKJUqVPorWLYk73l4ORc356SB4rbVlkosy0JpzeT0DKNDgyzWakzPzrFp /Trm5xc4dvw4Z2/dgtKaBx96mMsvu5TZ2Vm++djj3PDS6/H9gK/veIhLLjmfRr3Jjgce5ntedi1S Sj77uS9w3TVXUyoVufmTt/LyG16Kl8vxbx/+CD/0gz/AQLXC//nn93Dti1/Cxo3ruPmWW7n6qis5 75yz+ft//Gcue8ElvPiqK/nIf97CwECFV77iBv7r45/kqaf28Ztv/hU+fvOt1Gp1fuRHfoCP3fIp Pn375/jQv7yLL3z5bj772Tv5w9//TXZ8/QHe8pa/4I47PsmBg4f4oz98G295y+8zNz/Pb//OH/H3 f/cXFIp53vbnf8WP/PAP8aKrruTVP/BD/PzP/jSvftWNvOvd70UYw6/+8v/Pu9/zr7R8n1/8hZ/l Q//xMT772Tv58H+8l288+ijv/8CH+J3//b94cudu/vStf8Ftn/4vtNY8/uROfuM3f5v3vuddbNy4 MVUBG406f/bnf8Ub3/DDvOjqFwJw3/338853vZt3/u1fMj07x7v/5V9486/+KoVikZ/7xV/mz97y x5x39tn81d+8g5dedy033fS69jiQgps/9Wn+/QMf5vbbP9Gh1R09dozf/J0/4ff+969z1Qsv53d+ /4955cu/h//xUz+GZdscPnKEt/75X/JzP/vTvPyGl/Hef/0gQSvkr//qrdz71fv487f/Dfd97YuM jx/nr//6H3nbn/4h27dflLGLG97+9r8m31fk2mtfwo4dD/Erv/5bvGbf91Kr1/n1//XH/O3f/inX X/Ni/u3fPk65nOeSiy/i619/gA9/5Bb++YILOXjwEG//s3/gqstfQN852/i7d/wDr3nNq7nggvO4 5VO38eEP/xefvuUjzM7M8Sd//DZeeOVlDA8NcuuttzJYrXDtNS9h55O7+L3f/SNufMUrGBkd5i// 8u/5Hz/7E1x26XbuuftePnXrbbz6+27scBubVBQFIwxjIyO4jtNZyDljL8gGhBi9dAJOfh4eHOCa S89nbnONE8eOMjLYz2XnbWTrr/xP+stFNq7fzMte/GLmFhdxPQ8VBPQVCzSa9U2OU347cL0x5jeE EDPfVnGHWNSsx3/LptEYY/q/+sBDv/EHv/8Hb6o3aiPfeORhjh45yh133MmJiXkOLh5GCDh8+CgG wdhIhYLnUSwVCVotTpw4Qb3uYzsejmMTKoVtWRQKeQYGBiKVvFpldHSEocFB8vk8xVIJEUscYSgJ Ah+IquIUCwXKpRKv/8HXEGpF4AfMzs5x9NhRHn/iCcbHj6P3TXJ8ao65wRyzC5OErTrOoSKNJtiu zc5du5ifm6dULjE/W8O2HaZnZimVSriOzcjYCP3VfvqKRbx8jmK+EP2Wy+G5Dl6+wMTgAPOLi8xM TVHI5ZicmuQrd9/DyOgIfrPJx2++haHBAfYdOMjHb76Fl11/PROT0/zl37yTP3vr77AwX+P/+59v 5r67P4M2mj9969/wHx/6JxrNJv/rzX/Av7//n9h61ibe9U/v4Ybrr6NS6efNv/G7vPv/vpOhoSqf /ORnOWvrVs7Zdhb//N5/500GLr34Iu6440u88saXo1TIF770RfymD8ADDz5ApVLFaMPBAwc5tH8f APv372Pnzl2EYci+/Qd59InHAJiZmeWJXbsIlWJ+fp6vfXUHlmVRbzTYuWt36gSbmpkmCEMajQZf vvNu3vDGiHieePwJhoaGsCybw+PHcAuRFBn4AcePTSCF5Nj4CSanJ5FCoIkiDipDA5TLZRK91wB+ ENJSPpYbTXoC8FstCnmPUqnE5PQMu3c9Rd7zCPwAAoUOQ5TRhIFmaHgQKSIzSpSZpLGMZGhoMJZo spqBYHhgkHI56oPr1o6xdv0apLQQCHK5HJVyhcHqIEYbKv0VXMcFIunyoovPQwNKKbZs3kR1oNI9 6rjsBdsp9RXBQLlS5rqXXZNKTi+84gVs3rgBy5Js2bqJc7ZtwQBjY6Nc+oKLsW2bQiHPS69/EUND QwBcd921nHvuNiwpKReKXHrZRdi2RbFY4Id++PsZHh5AqZALzz+fs87eCsC6dWv5yf/+YwwODiCE 4LprX8LF55+PMbDt3LN5eeuGDpU88QG0zUKCvnJfRjtJCEOnpokl6nOXXTUxrY0NDTM2NAxEKaBS SK68dHvHoaMjS08Va0JrgZ8BRowxbzoj5vdXvvbHvviRf/vnl07PzlKt9IGBhYUFPv/5O9mzdy9g aLQa1Ost5mcmOH58gmazQaFYZGx0lIHKIMVCkWKxhDGKZstHKcXcwlSsTktq9RpKKRzHYXR0jG1n n0V/pZ9SsQQGJudqzM/O8ZpX3xhtI5rpk/JhydoqQgh0qPCDgJbfZG5xnoXFBZr1JrXFBhOTU0xM TLB71x527d2LY0KarRaO49Df14fjuHiFPEiBJSWO4+IHLWq1Gpb0CHyffKEAJqoM4LoOArBth8Xa ImvWrKG/3MfQyBAjIyOsGRvFshxGR4YiIp04wdo1Y/h+yK7de7j8Bdup1ep86tbP8dpXv5JWq8Un Pnk7N77yBoqFArd/9nO89jWvxsu5/OsH/p1Xfe+NFIsFvvTle7j66isYHKhy8ydv57JLLmLN2DD3 7XiYLZs3sX7dKPd+9WuUyyW2X3IJOx58iLHREdauWcP+/QdQYci2bds4dOgw8/NznHvuuRw6fIQj R49xzYuvYmZ2jr1PPcX2Sy6m0Wiye/ceLr/8MuqNJgcOHGTjhnWUikW+8eijbNm0CcdxefSxx9m6 dTMD1Sq79+wln88zOjrKsWPH0FqzaeMGGo0mMzMzjI6NMjMzw+TkFOeccw6NRgMhBLNzs6xbs4ZQ RwNDaYVSipnpaSqVCo7jorVmsVZjcXGBDevW0Wi2GB8fZ9OmjYRhyMzsLAPVKlJaHD8+ztDgEI7j ECqFY1sYBI1GHb/lU6lUUEqnBrwwDJmbn2ewUsGyLObnF/DyXqTBxAQxNz/PQLWCARYXazi2hevm aDQbaKWInYzMLyzQV+6L+mS7FB31eh3bsZHSQoUhfuBTLpVQ2lBbXIzIWAgWa3Xynoe0JL4foLXG 83IEQUiz2aSvHI2Der1BzovGkVIhSmlc1yFUGq0VtmWDiGoHyNg7LKVMnYtSSlq+Hz0jbUnWtu3U vp7A931c112S9x6GQTRpCJGm7FrSSug0o3rH00JHsZZO38vJEKrYXBM7b0T7HD7wT2eEED9522d+ tzow8BsDlUp/pVJlYnKKxx5/nPGjR/BbLaamZ9KGKOQ9bMvCGKjVFgmCgEa9wfz8An7gg4ZyXx99 fWVyBRdjImO0HXfUwPdZWFxgcnKKudlZtDFoo9iw7jze+MbXcdVVL8R1nLSDSRERY2p/Q0T1PgRE 5UQEQoOwBMZoglCR93Kp4yPwA+bn55iYmGBqaorx8XGOHjvG/MI8jUaDxcUaQeDjOi5KCSanJhkc HKRUKjMzM00+n2d6ZhZjNJX+fhqNFuVyGWM0R44ew7YtLGkRhgFGiKjz5jwuvugCQFAsFrDsiDCb rYBiqchgpZ9iqUC5XMLL5cnnvUh66u9DShuDwbasTKhSVC9ShdGAD1W8PXYUaaXbHv2M4ycxpqZh J7SdVTqu+iOE6LDTRqpOphhE5pzZ7KGsdNB2GEX3lBj6k/AVpQ2hUmAM0rKiikPxQNW6LXHozHaZ lT6SAZUYT6VIvSDRPekOx0ZnMH7bCWJo96Xs+BUdduboYdrnEdHkmOxIO1pCCBmFlGUi1pbNsxeS JKotOn/8zHSmkyaqJ7SdjG3brkDTWWAjff4kEaKDeEQcp9k+X7J2emfyQqZ4hhAdhJj9LYyrWyXk b1tWR03StIuJzvvqrHLVbsaViE1n3wnteivx452Z0vh33313WcHrwiD8Iw2ba/UWx48fZ+/u3WzZ splGvYHtRCl3Kgij5UYNaK1oNVsYDKVSCYOh0WhQq9Wp1+sorbEsm2KxhLRAKY3tOAgEzWYDz/O4 6MLzWTs2xtatW6lWqiitIgO1IY0/7GhYQKpomybuBLGhVytFqBSFfD4SzWXUYVutFvl8HiFEGlwa hgHzc/OcmDhBrVbDtm1arYCjx8aZn5/DDwKOHj3K1MwsUkr6+vspFgpMTU+DNhRyHrlcLu0JQghC pVBa02g0kUIyNT2F0pp6MyD0ferNFpYtKeYLeJ5DX1+JIAwp5guEKsSyXWzLYe3YCF7eY+OGjRSL BYYGB7FsSV+5j2IxihAIQx3nZydEEntCraRyVLajdgew0RH0HA2UqBPKaNnX2IvaJkvZ1fmz1XbS pSKkSM/d4eWMB6zWOiWVxAGXDLg0MkF0DaAlee+ZUKvOi3Q4jrL/Jk3Qfh7Tcb6TQSz33LDk/N37 dktY7W1L763Dzdv16rLE1P18nfe2TLzNKTjvuv1zvu+Tc3OdxGYMQRBEUqFlLXm+JW2UNSDGXkAr 7leJdzwNqDOZ6I+MXTLrhYeUKM/8WiEf+/jNH5mcmblU+cG2ffv3s3H9euG6OSzbwhiDY0d2QuJg 54X5BSampsiXCri2g2XbOLaD69pYjodt2eRcl5bfQghBqVRioNLPueeeQ39fH7ZlRUGfWneI5Umm SlYySDtjUmHHgCVFPEMLlApptVqUSp0l7uqNBoV8oR0aRBKiEanCAtJofCmiWKvsyw1UiDFw8NAh 3vmud/HFu+5h69p1NBtNtDYU8nkmJqcoV0r09/Xj+y0q1QqlYhEpLaqDg/h+QK1eJwwCGo0Wlg2e 62HF+d1gcF2XeqMZhw5FRL5YqxP4reg+gpCW38SyLLZsPpvq4AD95TJjY0OUiyUq1T4KhTKe55LL OUhh47g5bEuQz0ehLq7rRp3TtNWTUIUYInUvUqvakqTJSBhkJJZs2IrSOur0VrZMX7Zzm3YYS3xs 4lTL2vgSSW3ZgPAMAab9QYpUCkw0iOxBKTEmI4yuuFay41Z03OsSSa87KLHj6GysiyGbzZG9dsRP Sxkqoodo7+UiIXT8jAmhm+z3bABsNswjJppEQhRJA8f32mEXzNxvy/ejsJs4nCyRgputFlasDbV5 OxFU4iy0TDxUN3EdP34c3w9Yty6y10JSHi9RjxMTisayYulYg7TbYXrGrAIhGmPsJ5544pIvfvGL lyilSkNDQ780Pj6+rVar4eU9YedcpJTYtk2pWIpthQtUq0OEQUgzlhgFBq9QxGjD5PQ01WqFiy+4 gA3r1lIql6JYwlhFgjiWUSayRUa1S6QPQTsDJnVjxS8t/qyVwhiDl8ulnUcKweTUFAPVavpdxxJT d5WdpVV3oirQzWaL2bk5HnzoIb523w7m5mbZu28fYRgS+AFhqDDCkMvlmJmdw7IkZ2/dgiUtWr7P 8OAQtm0zMjJMsVCIbTuSiYnJSKrVCs91kZZNGAbxM4NtR2Q5OzdHvdZIQ4sC38dv+czOTqCCkEKx QC7ngYEQm7yXp1xqe/mdnItxHFTg49gu69evZaBaZaA6QKW/j/7+fvJ5j1IhH3XOOB9O68hGlbwL y7KwHStV4dq8mHgf22FBqbqXxO7pznTLuK/F5heTniORdkWmVmNCGlobbEuiDZFELS2kbKvayTkT itBKtwlupQ7fNXjbAeTf3tBb6WhzGvufTmTWimkoJ9u363cpBIePHKVQ8OL+FLVdGIY0G02q1Qqe 56VtetJnz0weUYhV5Jf4xjcf5SUvetES6Tr7vEKIyKwiRWo6SUSjM06Ine1m5F133TX62GOP5das WbMlCIKf2X/4wNpSsTwghTgnVMrL5XIiCEJs22V0dJQg8Gm2WmDAchwsabFYr3HBeeexedOmiJC0 plavY4wh57oQ24GSeDFio2qipqWDL840UUohpMw4XNp2sSNHjnJiaop1Y6P4QRBvN5y77SxUvBKg lBk1ZEkf6toWE3EQhigVRmqf1jRi4g8CRRAEKBXSaDZpNpvkPY+xsTEsKQiVpuW3mJ2bZ2Z6mgMH DrJmbIxGs8F/fuxmDh89SrW/j1arRS6Xj217abgwxkCpVEIbFc+sUV+zLYtWs0mz2WBxcQGtTZS7 niuilEYFAULKSGJ3HRzHQ4hIAqjX6xitCQIfjaHVUjhEjoN1G9dy7rlnUa1W6OsrMzgwQKlYpK9S xs3lKHiRvdN1XWzbAR29J8eNKtcrFeK6duq1TBxiid0xXZ1RJkHeOrZ/ddo2dSxBaqUx6GgVRxFJ DioMkVYk7bpxtfZI3bfQWqVxqJG5MJZlknjYjIS53PtOJLpvu0BKl/C49IdTGoErRNQvO1aXBMsv 15eXSN+Z79KS7N27l0as+TSbkanMdVxKpTJjY6N4uVwqpZ700UXbbCKloFarEQQhruNEQkGm/kBa JSvbbJnY4YwK/txbXtMYI3bt2rX2wUcefOHj33y8f9s52y5eWKzfdPzEiXWjoyMUC0Xh5ly00liO g5QSx3ai3MiY9JISYK7rUi6WcF038vTZdpStENsqosaK7E5pNfaEBIlsh1K2lz+VCJ7av58Dhw6z bs0YrWYLYQnKpTLbzjor8sQl2QQZNS15MR0vVXRVUM7aVLIxV+n+0Z4JiSeG9kR6FSK2jyE4fPQo N3/qU9x2+2c5fOgwgYoCy4cHB3CkRRiG0cxqWzi2w+zMDJYj6e+vki94FL0C1YEBSqUi+UIBrRXz 8wscOHAQjIXWIX7LBylwHBsVaOq1Oi2/hd9qYVkC18vTai0yMzsLxmLtmlGq1Qqtlo8fagqFIrZj YTsOrm1jFSKbaamQp1KpMjI8zEC1QrFYxHMdHDcaNMVCAaUMjmXTCgNsaVEqFtFExXmtNBMl6wAy kbRntaUBmRJn2y5pWaRtG5kZBEZF9TaTidGyZLoeSKLBJnbpdBBnkgU6wkS6vaRdYSSdHST7USzd flri3YpjrfO8K2UOnGaQfzcpdjvREntf23Fm0sDzjqWFM+aMbJtmbcDRO5QsLi6yWKtRrVSiilcr SogmdRSKJJupfe7nHiF249FHH3VvvfULI/v2PWW/9gf/2/VHDx/9kWPHjxWrlcFBz8tvDcIwL4BC sYhAxPbHqGBs0pZ5z8N2XXK5HJ7n4ToOOc/DdVxsx4pUtbjAbNLgiXqduOiFENiWHS9XYIGIXmg2 JdAkZfA7VPOON5vZljH4m8QzJjJ2kmyfyhq8V57Qk76otabVbHJicoJWy2d6dpaZmRmOHzvO5MQJ 5uYWWIg7kNIG2xL0l8v0VSpgDFNTUzRaAUEQYjs2QwNDrF07SqvZYufOvQRBizBIVHnioPPoiX3f p9FsYLSh2awRhgohLNycG0lXCHI5L61QpLVChwq3WMS27djOE7WtMj6GAIGh1mhQKhbor+T52Z/6 FbZs2khfuUyyRndaLT31CifLT8h22iORPdj3/bbUmKrhGikiO2UYBDhO1F8sq62St/wWIMi5Llac 0ikgsn2JyJmWSDeRjUrH3/Wy3vglWNa2+ewTosl0niV31SUVLnuek1wj6f+pTVAIuoWDrG1w+U7e lsKXk0wT85WO29laIdsluU7yThJHahJtoZTSz3lCXPbBjHH27Nlz8Zfuvvu/nRgf94rF0uVC8Crf DyiVSliWFHkvslf5cTK5im1UiZPBjUuXOY7TQZTSsqLBKkRq5JWJrUFEC1pF2+KQHCnSYN9Ereqo trNsmMRylCY6Onu3fX2JvX05ZGbNRGJOwmtS72oMHXtltY47kWNhSwttDNPT0+zatYc9T+1n9959 TExOUan0MT5+AseSSAFhqAl8nyAMCAIfP2jihwHNZhOlQhzHpdUM0SaSmkOlMVohjAKt0tAK13UA gdECx4kyfIRlY0uHXD6Hl3fpL5c599xtXHfNS1i7di0hUXSBib2LIs5pt4RM7aKWbUdkFa/MJaWV hsRIKdNQnsSeml33JZE0G02fRqOObdvRpBpHQthxaE/HuuCA47ixXVqnds7ETqp19sWZk7/Hjlcq 0kX9lgiUJzlHYjvvvk5HauYp3MfTqfamzfTL9kexpF+LZTi9M/V05c7d+RzQ5s62RpUNBWtL8e3f ogOU0ql0qI2hXq/Ravnj35GE2I1HH3209Pm77hpqzMy42y+77MZ9e/f+wv4DB7wLzj+/LIQYBKIs BSGiODWjkdLCcZI4RgtL2nh5D9d1sB2XnOtiO5FE6DqRSi5ENJCkkFiWHa+QJjMkKVLbY1LFO+mY SSWcxNMcqjA6X/yqEnT7FzuwnEC/QuSDiHcXhi71OlXm09nbJPsk3koZq+BS4FgOYRDQCgLu/ur9 vPOd/5f5xXlyrhvZ+Swby5W4lkWlWmVxcRGlFQUvj8BOybjeauG6DjnHRREtZedIGzeXA6Nx8x5+ K6TcX8SoiEjCQLN1yxauvupK+sqlqNJQkvEgoODl8HIu/X39UaByYj4gsRHRWezjJIM7ddIQHTM1 u8hDj+6hv1xgYX4GaUEQ+pRLVXbvepx/ec/fMTAwyutf/waueck1jAwPEwY+pThAOpEKdWzD1Eaj wijaYSW97FTW13k6DTbNfV/6hO2qN9k+Zrr3iv4v4hIUieDWHcXTTaqJShyV9YqiRLJ9rX120XGe bG9P7225SJ/sw2eeMdti2ftKzxM7UHRcqyCpqqO1ptFoELR8MzV5wtdaf2lsbMNvPy8IcTkYY5x7 77332i996UvX1Wo1cdH2i39lcbHW5/stXNcV+XwhtQVlE8qllDiuhxSSnJfDdRxsx8a2HRzHxnFc pIzUZyEjYkxsS4kKbVttp0oSd2dJi6QgpozXF04kzOXsR2KFTtTdS046Q5OZcTOa+FI7ehwQTdvQ nBxkWRZT07M8/I1Hufe++wnqNWq1OguLCwRBSBgEBKGP7Vp4rkdfXxkv71Gr1ekr9qXZQ6FS+K0W Ti6H7boYNMJEzhLbspF2JOmpMApt2rplMxecdy4bN2yg3qiT2JFarRZevkijWefLX7mL//7GNzAy MtzlLGq3S+KB7G7KbiklIod2SMze/YdZbISoVoNf/tXf5Nzzt/JzP/OTPLXvEFqHNOvThKGi0QwZ Gh4FYSEwvPGm16N0TH4ZFokcOCoNITIrvd5lsIQoY2brcHSkmkRiAkhiC0U6IXYHTS9PK+010BPn UzscJ5rkEzt2tm9po9PA8yzPiSV9V3RuT5+hTZ2pfb3TgJ6q9iJ7/2m4UjvWtB0lEh2ktIrMO1qh tML3A06cOMHC4iIo/Z851771+uuvfz88txaqf0YhhAiALwBfMMbIT3/m0585fmIyhwmLa0fX/PDR 8aMvnpubzQ0ODVZcx+mLJEEXLUCFmiQ9y7FtPM+LQlJilcl1XGw7Ltjg5CIJMa7UkTh1EqmwHXcn U2eN7Tip1xvd7rxJAIfsmOXbHXYl9eXkC84n8XHRaUQS0pBRI0w6k7Y95CZeSVAISV+pyEUXnEt/ fz8P7NjBrp27mZ6dQytN3sthW3akQgrDzp27OHvb2RSKBZ7at59KpUp/fxmt2yXTWn4Tx3Eo5Aux oyNaBiJUIdVKhStecBlbNm8i5zrUags4jhMthh4ECOGQy7n4rSZnbdlCtVKJogKE6BjwHZkohiWf TRcXZHcJghCjDetGh3j7W9/KwvQ4cxNFDh88iFI+QeATaoO0bNycZGLiBNoItl9yEWGo4ogBhdZt zz20PdupbXGZ97Tc98Qc03Gjgg7Czf6WqqWZWE8hojA0Y9pOxOUsN6lwljoHM9eJiSfsqDsaE2cc ZiaTSlodE0+3DbT9MJEDsXOf1NGxQj/PxqmaTEZREnmQmEEQAr/VotlqEYYh9XrN1BZr4czc3FFL sFti/ePWrZvuPv/886c6bu+7FVNTU337Du674f777nvtsWNH5Flnb7u+2WhuUlqQLxREVKVbpule Xj5yxIQqxHFdiEM1LCv2dNtWXHknsiM6jo3r5lKVWhuNUTo6NrZHJh7p1Pgs2p7mJQpS/NKTgNkk EFfHQeSmu9/RrT61bUbtsmkGY9ppbmnmQBhQKBTjIFqwbRvHsck5Ls1WiyNHjnL48GGOn5hkYX6e r9x9D3ue2sO1L34JC7UF9u7fx8H94xij2bZ1K+ecsw3XtWkFQeRptCxyuRy1eh1tFGvG1jA2NsLF F15AX7mPeqOBbUlcx6JYKvONbz7KiYkJjo2PUyj088CDD/Frv/jzXHrxhZhEWkolG7E8t5zMHiFA mGhYLyzW8AMFWvP6H/x+LNvh4ksuZcvWLfhBi/Ub1lIul5mdm2N+boFNGzdx6SWXUCyVopx1qx1c nNiXozanHVqVvM/0BhOn2jITX1cXSM6VFlbMPFuS/ytEFGhvWZJ6o0GpFIVLaa1S76owLOHhJP3O caJwo8SeioBWyydZHlhIiRVLn4n3mDTOM0u2mWU3MpJhot7altUhabbbIRPKlDRDahBsB/SnDitj 4knIoLSiWa/Tavk0/RaNep3FxcXAduyvObZ919qxsfdfeumlu5bjhOethHgqGBwcnAc+AXzCGCNu u+227Tt27KiMjo6O5PO5N+/cufMKS9qsXbsG23HEXffchWVZvOTqFyGIil0mhJmE+liWhbTaYT9R HCRYVkQoYahwAz+SGGOibdvtMoHgqdjfZrq2OtRtL+mcS9Oc4Ph7QnzpZ5PxhMYOACmt2EMfe6lb PgIZS7kiLvGu0crEmSyb2Lx5UxyuInnV972SH7jpDVx7zYt50dVX8V+f+AR/97fvYm6hTrNZp1jM R0TXaqCMxrZstDaMDg+zZs0o27dfQn9fmXy+gBSCocFBXNfh4Ue+yfvf8X8RAjZuWM/IyAhDlUG+ aX2T887ZlnrJk2xMY0y0frYR6cDKZhDFDbbUnpiRrrQ2FLwcTzz2GNK2sBwPaXn0V4cYHuqP0hz7 +1kzthaIohjGx4/FRGPhxPZq27LSgMU0nhUyUlKnmJpMht3oyJmmS8jqOodtWwR+lAbnOA7TMzM8 uXMXW7ZsjsrcOQ5aKVq+jy2s2BKReNxJKxLl8x6tZisqOtFoRgHz0qLVios4aE1odJobbMVSWyIF i+yUnHmu7OMJIQjjbOKEWNOF5EybEJOIgORREyeVIZK2tdKEStFqtQiCgDAI8f0Wtdoi9XqdfL5w YGRk+I8vveSST1QqlZmTccJ3NSFmEZcyeziz6aMQLYt69913/9Kjjz++uVGvezt3Pnnd/V/fsfb7 v/+1jI2NCdfJxaQWeTzDwI+DRSXNZvSywyCyHVUq/ZFHN/Z2E4fySGkhZez9FDIKGk/U3Gxgq2x3 mE4bS9sU01aj2p1KK9OecUUUppIammMpQBJVME5m2JnpWQyS/r4ShUJsG8zlqPRV8fI5QKTOJtux WLN2Dfd88U6On5jkrnu/xmOP7aQ60McFF2xjbnaBT95yO9KCYqmEl89RrfTj5nIMDw7yPddfi+c4 HD92nCd3PsnxE5Ps2rOH+x98jJ/8qR/nVTd+L+VyH65jUygWqC/Ms3PPHvJ5Lwrw9X0saaU554kj KbFppRNCajcQGQJst2+UwmbSyWv/vj088PAOXv2aNzA8toZWK1KF/bBByw/ARBVdROy9lNJOpfdc zkUbYi969M5zrht5vzOhHskrFpDGT7ZV/24vcLStnYqXCWtJpLI4Fc6yLZozs+S9PNvOPhvLslhY rEVB50k/WzIIInIMw4BWyycMAjwv5I47v8CWs7awaePGNIbVcV3CIGhneiWhZsu0azy+UhU+Wzeg raUkK2lGhToiwouKPog0gywiWqWiClOBH2KMwugomN73A/wwQAimm83m3eVCYe+Lr776ndu2bdt7 qjzQI8SnQTyj/AnA7t27c/fdd9/1d9xxx9pDBw45WzZtub7RaLxhcXFRhmFAsViiUCgI24nWjFBa RVkWjkvec2k162AiNSOpEi2EE+fomrbdRLTXgJbSiiryIFBGpfanqLx74iFux2hprdvkBxil49AP gzIahU5JNVp6wSBU1BlVbHQ2xuC3AlQQ0qjNE4aKZrPJnj17KZTLXHzhBeTzBbxcDjfn4OVyOK7L 4UNHuOuee3ls126CRgPQlEpFhoeHGF0zxLHxExw+eAhLwpOPLjA0OsKRw0dYmJ/Gkg4zM7PMzc9R 6a8Chssvu5hrrr6SaqWCJSU5zyPnOuzbU2dxfg6Iq2/H+a8mziiBKB41Cr7XJGQYjVUNRtDpjc0a GEDpEIRDrdmkMjiM67oEoWLN2DCt+jRSKkLCSMLx23Y2S9qpFNNqNZFS0GxY6aQRhrk2GYrIj5vm XsdXF6IdChTBIEQSyiVS8dAklWUQERnFfSSV9uL9Wq1Wl6ZA2h4qDDs8t5AESMfRBkKwuLjI9u2X YIjCsTDtIq4m02ZkrqGUxpICEQfJJ/bM7ESe2K5tyyJUIWGoUqdTalowBlvKuNhyZJ+0bBsd1zFt +S38epNWbCOsVqsHHDv3/lqt9tgrbrjh8xs3bpw93XWZe4R4Gti2bVsL+Fzy/R3veMe7gR+HSJI8 fPjwa3bs2PFTBw/up1QqFtauXb/R9/3hAwces5RSDI8NC8uSFApFKpUqSqlUXbVilUrFRnc7XlxL KZWGcURFIaJOq1V22eyMd9WY9vodtOPhUlWZRCWJwkGM0WhjdUiSUYdTBIGPUiE518XLOQwM9LNv /yH6y2W0UswvLOD7QXyvGtd1KeTzvPDS7TSaTWamJujv72NhscbiYg0v53DeeWdHudJxdZNXvuJ7 aDYa9PVX2Lp1C47rIoRkanKKs87azOUXXxCpYhn7phAGP84rT0I82jnKmRQ90eU4yMT/psUHsh7P +Dqzcwuxd32aSqHK4NAw69eNce45Z7FjxzjSKKTVzl4RSXiTVqnkpdEIE5XiUkIjQk1DhfG8lyxU JmPHVZfXlqzzVSx5z5H0S1pEwyQHkHjVMyYWMs65bF9YAVHfantrs5V9kuu0w2yycbKddr1owjWx VEdHqIwVx/AiRUbKbD9iEo1hCYmfpIBqhRAmNgW4TaXUkemp6UNjIyMnrrjiivddeOGFdwghwm93 jPcI8RlCLEl+IP7j0UcfLS0uLl66Z8+uLcViwcrnc+7QyPCNc7Oz10xNnhhqNmrkXA/bcbAtWxBL fFacMeP7zYwaQTRYVZxzmwkIjgSCuFCByVRmie2D0I5DTLZrrTHKxBKnAcuNJETVnqUD30cYcG2L +bk5Ws0mQsCWzZuoLy4wtzBH3sujwoAwaIIQnDhxHKNVlDWgDLOzs8zPzxOEAVoZhBV52oMgoL+v jyd27uQNP3ITExMTaB2pgZGHVzM9PUO+UGB8YirKqAkjiSEMQ/bseYq5uQWMiSrqCEGa7ihEJDVF Hl6xbOxmIkW1/RGxrBOT1fT0LI5t4fua/uowA5Uqmzaup1wqMjM9Qz5nk/M8LGlj2VZUszKu4Zld 6MyK86GFY1EsFLEti8VaDT+IVHytNSoMUgJXKsr8sR0bx3Ii51bQiiX5pfF7YfwlWRxMIog08Wxo TfT/tDSYaaupgQoze0VtoDUYLdr9xLRTH9O2i8+jY60mUeETe23SZ9NFuYTApNKfIUyvFptvTFQg Vsde8GbLp9VsMjE9xdzMLBs2bGDzxo3Hy+XSbdOzU/cODg7MnHPWOQ+fjip8qugR4rOEiy66aBG4 O/5L8M/ZfWZmjm0+enTyhompyUsnT5zYNjk5kZudnaVWa5DLOViWTV9fuezlCyXHdvJSkjMYyxgt jcZGIJTSkXO0CwlpakzkY8gOhkhdFkopYYyh2ZrHRKvWiSAIRahC4bd8Xa/VNODFZbdUo9EQjUZT ul4h1EqJVqNhB0FgCSGVJTF9paLtR/nMaqFVx/M8oZQOMML3vFxtcbEe7tmzrzE7MVFvNBqNCy46 N/zyl798reu4DAwO02o24/Q4yfj4MaYXFrjrq/cxP7+YSg7GaA7t3Y0tVDwYTVS7MXro1I6YlpAT S4kk/d7l+ZQyKg919NgJms0mlmUzNrqO4aEhNqwfIwxazM3NYVWrhKYFopVmLVkyCtzvyLYQoEJF w29y1RUvpFodYM/efbT8FrZlE6oQNDiOHcWjxuEwiXNASksVCvmGMSoQckmUjjDGOBHhWAiBjpZS ALQRgIiIP6apdK40IpGUQxXk4nOl/zcghZGpsy1NgyRx7rUlRtu2U8kvfeDYBpgtISakCC1ptQym EaqwXl+szzeajYVave7PzswQhAHNZovQD9DaMLZmlMsvu3zhpddd++krr7zyX+K1nM4IeoS4iqhW 1+wH3rvS78YYubCwUJ2YmBio1+v9Simv1Wq5WgeWr3wnbBlLCCWMsUwsL8SwEUJo27YJw9DEqyUS 7RO9cqWUiOPSUUoIhUIaKZUQQqjo/1JKs7i4WJBSGiGENsZIpbA8z2n5vrJAWUEQ2FoI7UhpWq3Q CYKAfCkfOFIapYzllgqNYr7U6C+W5nM5r1ksugtQnN28eXj+S1/6cvjxT3zynk/fdusVA9URinkP bSLbX73eQOujHDuwh4X5OSzLJsoftyLbURB5SlXsXUxy10WsKqswjMJKMjaszD8xOuM7bQRKw+zs HLXFBZSK7IIDA1WqlX727tvLxz9xCyUvz8iG9alU6jhR1pPjuJEkLCWlQgHLtgiDkMsuu5Tzzjuf J57cxY77H8SxXbxiVGzEdRwajSb7Duxn/PAxBvoi08Gll26/y7LFBwYGho97ntOSUnYQYqvVslut Vk44Qsd9Jf1dRO7b9HNoQmlhoYQSQrVboFarFTJ9zcT9wtJ6aUpv1gmUoNlsorrnYhXZmx3HwfVc PM+jUCy0il6x1t/fvzgwMDBTKBSm1q5dOwk0TtfG92yjR4jPYQghNDAV/z3vcMVVVwH89czkiV9w BCMW/eunpqZLs7OzLCwsIKXk3nWjjI2N0mr55L1cZF+cnsPC8NT+/VQHBkGAHzSigr5xgLxSKl73 WKYLD2WXQk3W1Ehi9kAShAopYHp6Aq0VuZzHpm1r6asUogB0LFzpMT/fIDx8glzOw3Ys8gUPCPBc HQfgC3xfY0kbbTSfvePLfP4Ld6G0oVwuUchLAloY04pSOo1hcmKeoycmQVlcPLiewbVb1PlnnfOV 9ev7d30bTdzDaaJHiD2sGnZ87WsAH9Naf+zJJ5+8/JFHHnnR+973vspdd92F1kpeddULr6lWq9c/ +eROcezYMYaHh1lYWBCVygBBq8kDDz3Ey2+4gRMT09iWxLaiNb9tS8bFKwyu6xCEYbxGB+24z8Rb m6SjWVaUfmlAq4Dp6RlQhlKxihQuvq/Yvv3iXX/ylj/46Fe+8hX1tfsfvn5+fuGl+XyOgWqFhYVF QssGExGi0QbhRHZEx4rWmU7WI64tLmJ0gTAMyeVc8vk8npdjYXYRVRnBdR0cxzqrHtZ74/MMo9fg PawaYlU10fXvi/8AuPnmmwEq4+PjlX379nHixAle97rXrTnvvPN+4eDBQ9ccPH6EL9z5BVkul6v5 fKHPcR1yrpdmFbmuSxgqisU8YRDF3tmOndr4EsdHovZaVhT56Xkerm1x+NAhNm1Yj2uX8byyUYow l8v91o033njLuz78YVMaHaru3bPvK5VK+aLawgJ9/X0YHanYqf1MRhWTpCWj0CAVEvhNAr9F6EfO koYlaXp5dBgg0NTrixzY/xTr1w03a41GbbXf0XcbvqtT93r4zsWRI0cIw7D4uTvufO/48Ymb+vr7 sRwnWtIgLuvmt/x4Sc7oGBmTlWVFEqHISIi2FaVguo7Dzid3ctttt1MqlLj4shdzzTUvOrF5y/r3 bFw79LvJ9T/4wf8AeO373/+vv1SpVG6QthRzM7V4lb+QRq1Oo9lksdbEcsAPQwwizv228Jst1qwd o6/cx8DAAOVSGa2VPzkx98jjj+++/fd+75c/cdNNNz282u383YaehNjDdyTWrVvHnXfeWduyaePt Dz3w0JVHDu0XlWplwPPyhUKhYBNnORzc16K/Ukkrn0M7XhA6y1Y1Wn6UTolkYW6OI4cO4ZTK5vob rrqzEdT+JXv9n/iJHwX45Ec/+tGHa7Xa1tnZWRYXoyDhyclxHn30SRYW5hk/PElpyGNxsUkzhJIX FQtZnF2k0tfHurERNm1Yy7p16+jvHwzPPfesI9u3b9930013n26T9PAMoCch9vAdjziAuPDEE09c /9T+Pd+z/6l9A48+9hjT0xNMT02Jiy++dKQ6UF0rhRyW0iojhCeldJLAYykxruPVG34wMzs1MzE+ fnzvXXfdtXjpJRfzsle+gpte97o/Xrt27YHVfs4enn30CLGH5y3i4GKxf//+vjAMB6empoqzs7PF Wq3mhGFohWFkvrQsy/T39zer1Wq9UqnMn3/++eNCiNZq338PPfTQQw899NBDDz30sNr4f8FHDu7H 8GLiAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA1LTMwVDIzOjA3OjIwKzAzOjAwoTRixQAAACV0 RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNS0zMFQyMzowNzoyMCswMzowMNBp2nkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
    <defs>

        <pattern id="a" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/9/9a/Etihad_Airways_logo.png" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>


    <g>
        <path fill="url(#a)" d="M20 5h15l45 50H40z" />
        <circle cx="293" cy="63" r="8" fill="url(#a)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the error "Failed to find definition for url(#patternDefined)".
so just convert the image to svg using this website https://onlineconvertfree.com/convert-format/png-to-svg/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert Svg online who can produce SVG without pattern tag because it's not supported by the flutter_svg plugin.

You can also use png file and change the color of image using color parameter in png file in app.